# Window scrollTop returns 0 at the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery

I have the following function where I want to add some delay to some of the elements in the animation, but only if the page has not been scrolled. For that, I check the $(window).scrollTop(), however, it returns also 0 if I scroll and then reload the page.
Can anyone tell me why does that happen?

```
slideInAsScroll: function() {
  var win = $(window);
  console.log(win.scrollTop());
  var allMods = $(".load-group");
  // Already visible modules in the viewport
  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-in");
      if (
        win.scrollTop() == 0
      ) {
        $(".come-in:nth-child(2)").css("animation-delay", ".5s");
        $(".come-in:nth-child(4)").css("animation-delay", "1s");
        $(".come-in:nth-child(5)").css("animation-delay", "1.5s");
        $(".come-in:nth-child(6)").css("animation-delay", "2s");
      }
    }
  });
  // Not visible modules in the viewport
  win.scroll(function(event) {
    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
      var el = $(el);
      if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("come-in");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: How is your html looking?

Comment: there is no height given to the body or to the parent div within the body, if that`s what u are thinking

Comment: scrollTop() should not be 0 if you scroll to bottom and windows has a height

Comment: You want people to debug a web page .... and you're not supplying the page.  Not sure that's going to be successful.  Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: I have edited my description of the problem, maybe it is more understandable?